# Powershell regex producing different result than.NET online tester

Tags: powershell

I am trying to read parameters from a file and automatically assign them to variables in powershell. But I am getting a different output when using regex in powershell compared to using the corresponding .NET regex flavor.

here's the content of my input file (install.ini):

```bsh
[sqlinstall]

Switch Parameters 
------------------
Active = "Off"
Install = "false" 
Update = "false"
Config = "false"
Local = "false"
New_Variable = "Test Variable"

Path Parametres 
----------------
InstallPath =  "C:\"
```

I've extracted the content by using the following powershell script (extract.ps1):

```bsh
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot
$checkfile = "install.ini"   
$readfile = Get-Content $checkfile
$filecontent = "$readfile"

# REGEX FILTER Install.ini
# -------------------
# Getting all 'switchname = switchvalue'
$regex_equals = '(?m)(?<switchname>\w+)(?=)\s*=\s*"(?<switchvalue>\w+|.*)"'   

#Getting all folder paths: 'pathname = C:\ or C:\FOLDER\filde.pdf'
$regex_path = '(?m)(?<pathname>\w+)(?=)\s*=\s*\"?(?<pathvalue>\w:\\*[\\]{1}.*\w|\w:\\)' 

# get everything: 'Parameter = Fullpath, Filepath, Filename, ext'
#$regex='(?<ParameterName>\w+)(?=)\s*=\s*\"?(?<FullPathAndFile>(?<FilePathOnly>\w:\\*[\\]{1}.*\"?)\\(?<FileName>\w+\.(?<Extension>\w{2,3})))'

$options = @('MultiLine') #[Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]'Multiline'


# READ Install.ini ('switchname = switchvalue')
#---------------------------------------------
#[regex]::matches($filecontent, $regex_equals, $options) 
$null = [regex]::matches($filecontent, $regex_equals, $options) | % { $_.Groups[1].Value } -OutVariable switchname
$null = [regex]::matches($filecontent, $regex_equals, $options) | % { $_.Groups[2].Value } -OutVariable switchvalue


# READ Install.ini ('pathname = C:\ or C:\FOLDER\filde.pdf')
#---------------------------------------------
#[regex]::matches($filecontent, $regex_path, $options)
$null = [regex]::matches($filecontent, $regex_path, $options) | % { $_.Groups[1].Value } -OutVariable pathname
$null = [regex]::matches($filecontent, $regex_path, $options) | % { $_.Groups[2].Value } -OutVariable pathvalue


#Asssign file parameters to Variables 
#-------------------------------------
$dollar = "$"
$mark = '"'

<#
('switchname = switchvalue') => $Active       = "Off"
                                $Install      = "false" 
                                $Update       = "false"
                                $Config       = "false"
                                $Local        = "false"
                                $New_Variable = "Test input"

#>

foreach ($name in $switchname ) {
  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $switchname.Count; $i++) {
    switch ($switchname[$i]) {
      ($name) { New-Variable -Name $name -Value $switchvalue[$i] }
    }
  } 
}


#('pathname = C:\ or C:\FOLDER\filde.pdf') => $InstallPath =  "C:\"

foreach ($name in $pathname ) {
  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $pathname.Count; $i++) {
    switch ($pathname[$i]) {
      ($name) { New-Variable -Name $name -Value $pathvalue[$i] }
    }
  } 
}
```

When testing the regex online it shows no errors for both patterns:

- [Online Test Pattern1](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%28%3F%3Cswitchname%3E%5Cw%2B%29%28%3F%3D%29%5Cs*%3D%5Cs*%22%28%3F%3Cswitchvalue%3E%5Cw%2B%7C.*%29%22&i=%5Bsqlinstall%5D%0D%0A%0D%0ASwitch%20Parameters%0D%0A-----------------%0D%0AActive%20%3D%20%22Off%22%0D%0AInstall%20%3D%20%22false%22%20%0D%0AUpdate%20%3D%20%22false%22%0D%0AConfig%20%3D%20%22false%22%0D%0ALocal%20%3D%20%22false%22%0D%0ANew_Variable%20%3D%20%22Test%20input%22%0D%0A%0D%0APath%20Parametres%0D%0A------------------%0D%0AInstallPath%20%3D%20%20%22C%3A%5C%22)
- [Online Test Pattern2](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%28%3F%3Cpathname%3E%5Cw%2B%29%28%3F%3D%29%5Cs*%3D%5Cs*%5C%22%3F%28%3F%3Cpathvalue%3E%5Cw%3A%5C%5C*%5B%5C%5C%5D%7B1%7D.*%5Cw%7C%5Cw%3A%5C%5C%29&i=%5Bsqlinstall%5D%0D%0A%0D%0ASwitch%20Parameters%0D%0A-----------------%0D%0AActive%20%3D%20%22Off%22%0D%0AInstall%20%3D%20%22false%22%20%0D%0AUpdate%20%3D%20%22false%22%0D%0AConfig%20%3D%20%22false%22%0D%0ALocal%20%3D%20%22false%22%0D%0ANew_Variable%20%3D%20%22Test%20input%22%0D%0A%0D%0APath%20Parametres%0D%0A------------------%0D%0AInstallPath%20%3D%20%20%22C%3A%5C%22)

Powershell shows correct results for most variables:

```bsh
------
INPUT:
------
Write-Host $Active
Write-Host $Install
Write-Host $Update
Write-Host $Config
Write-Host $Local
Write-Host $InstallPath
------
OUTPUT:
------ 
Off
false
false
false
false
C:\
```

But it doesn't produce correct output for all variables:

```bsh
------
INPUT:
-----
Write-Host $New_Variable
------
OUTPUT:
------
Test Variable"  Path Parametres ------------------ InstallPath =  "C:\
```

Maybe I put the multiline option incorectly ? Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ini file looks a bit odd because it has strings and separator lines in it that should not appear in an ini file.

Anyway, using a helper function, you can parse the file to receive an (ordered) Hashtable with the properties from the file:

```
function Parse-Ini {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        $Content
    )

    # PowerShell < 3.0
    # $ini = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary([System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    $ini     = [ordered]@{}
    $section = "UNDEFINED"
    $line    = 0

    $Content | ForEach-Object {
        $line++
        switch -regex ($_) {
            # a section
            '^\s*\[(.+)\]\s*$' {
                $section = $matches[1].Trim()
                if (!($ini[$section])) { $ini[$section] = [ordered]@{} }
                break
            }

            # a property: Key = Value
            '^\s*([^#]+?)\s*=\s*(.*)' {
                if (!($ini[$section])) { $ini[$section] = [ordered]@{} }
                # remove inline comment, trim and unquote
                $name, $value = ($matches[1..2] -replace '#.*$').Trim() -replace '^(?:"(.*)"|''(.*)'')$', '$1$2'
                $ini[$section][$name] = $value
                break
            }

            # skip comment and empty or whitespace only lines
            '^\s*#?$' { }

            # bad entry
            default {
                # comment out the next line if you don't want to seen the warnings
                Write-Warning "Bad entry detected in line $($line): '$_'"
            }
        }
    }

    return $ini
}
```

With this function in place, you call it like:

```
$Params = Parse-Ini (Get-Content -Path 'D:\install.ini')
```

which gets you a Hashtable with one entry `sqlinstall` that contains another Hashtable with all properties you are after:

```
$Params.sqlinstall
```

> ```
> Name                           Value
> ----                           -----
> Active                         Off
> Install                        false
> Update                         false
> Config                         false
> Local                          false
> New_Variable                   Test Variable
> InstallPath                    C:\
> ```

and to obtain the different entries, simply use the dot-notation like

```
$installPath = $Params.sqlinstall.InstallPath
```

Because of the invalid entries mentioned earlier, the function will emit warning messages. If you don't care about these messages, just comment out the line `Write-Warning "Bad entry detected in line $($line): '$_'"`

Comment: That's awesome, exactly what I wanted to achieve! Thank you Theo! Works perfectly. Any Idea why my regex didn't work ?

Comment: @HectorEduNseng To be honest I didn't try your regex code because it looked to be far too complicated and dedicated to handle this one file content only. What I saw was an ini file (although with some invalid lines in between) that could be handled in a more generic fashion. Glad you liked my answer!

Comment: @HectorEduNseng I have just updated the function with better code to remove inline comment, trim and unquote the name and value for an entry. Enjoy!

Comment: :))) I'm really happy about your code Theo! Thank's alot!

Answer (score 1):

How about using a proper Powershell Data File? It's easy to read and easy to create or manipulate and even easy to load and use.

Your example parameter file would look like this:

```
@{
    SwitchParameter = @{
        Active       = 'Off'
        Install      = $true 
        Update       = $false
        Config       = $false
        Local        = $false
        New_Variable = 'Test Variable'
    }
    PathParametres = @{
        InstallPath = 'C:\'
    }
}
```

And assumed you named it `install.psd1` you could import it like this:

```
$Params = Import-PowerShellDataFile -Path .\install.psd1
```

Now you could use the contained variables like this:

```
$Params.SwitchParameter.Install
#or 
$Params.PathParametres.InstallPath
```

That would be much easier and more professional than using string and regex acrobatics. ;-)

Comment: Olaf..if I had a heart emoji  for loving a code I'd send you one :) That 's perfect ! Thank's alot for helping out.

Comment: I'll do, as soon as I pass my "stackoverflow novice" status of 15 reputations lol 
Again .. Thank you!